# init state variable from another binding value - variable self used before being initialized

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to init a toggle selector with a conditional clause. If we display the 'FREE' plan, it should be selected by default (Option #3). I am struggling to init the State from the Binding showFreeversion.

```
struct PricingView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var showFreeVersion: Bool
    @State private var selectedPrice: Int
    
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, showFreeVersion: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self._showFreeVersion = showFreeVersion
        self.selectedPrice = showFreeVersion.wrappedValue ? 3 : 0
    }
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Variable 'self.selectedPrice' used before being initialized
```

But if I init the state to 0, it won't change to 3 by default if there is a free version.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize State as below

```
init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, showFreeVersion: Binding<Bool>) {
    self._isPresented = isPresented
    self._showFreeVersion = showFreeVersion
    self._selectedPrice = State(initialValue: showFreeVersion.wrappedValue ? 3 : 0)
}
```